# Flutter web - Firebase Messaging handling background notifications

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter-web, firebase-notifications

I'm using firebase messaging in my flutter web app and I could receive and deal with the sdk and everything is working just fine on the foreground using this function:

```
 import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as firebase;
 class PushNotificationService {
  firebase.Messaging _mc;
  Future initialise() async {
   _mc = firebase.messaging();

    _mc.onMessage.listen((event) {
   print('New Message: ${event.data}');
    }
  }
 }
```

But when I try to listen to the background events using this code:

```
_mc.onBackgroundMessage.listen((event) {
      print('New Message: ${event.data}');
});
```

I receive an exception:

`FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a service worker context. (messaging/only-available-in-sw). at ot.setBackgroundMessageHandler (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.1/firebase-messaging.js:1:38164) at messaging.Messaging._fromJsObject.[_createBackgroundMessagedStream] (http://localhost:14698/packages/firebase/src/messaging.dart.lib.js:100:23) at messaging.Messaging._fromJsObject.get onBackgroundMessage [as onBackgroundMessage] (http://localhost:14698/packages/firebase/src/messaging.dart.lib.js:76:51) at firebase_push_notification_service.PushNotificationService.new.initialise (http://localhost:14698/packages/bpazar/catalog/presentation/bestSelling/best_selling_ui.dart.lib.js:155066:19) at initialise.next (<anonymous>) at runBody (http://localhost:14698/dart_sdk.js:38027:34) at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:14698/dart_sdk.js:38058:7) at firebase_push_notification_service.PushNotificationService.new.initialise (http://localhost:14698/packages/bpazar/catalog/presentation/bestSelling/best_selling_ui.dart.lib.js:155059:20) at setUpNotifications (http://localhost:14698/packages/bpazar/catalog/presentation/bestSelling/best_selling_ui.dart.lib.js:147880:40) at setUpNotifications.next (<anonymous>) at runBody (http://localhost:14698/dart_sdk.js:38027:34) at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:14698/dart_sdk.js:38058:7) at home.HomeViewState.new.setUpNotifications (http://localhost:14698/packages/bpazar/catalog/presentation/bestSelling/best_selling_ui.dart.lib.js:147878:20) at home.HomeViewState.new.initState (http://localhost:14698/packages/bpazar/catalog/presentation/bestSelling/best_selling_ui.dart.lib.js:147459:12)`

So my question is:
Is there any way to deal with background notifications in flutter web?